# Java : reading data and comparing then writing

Tags: java, if-statement, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I'm writing a program to read data from a text file (grades), compute the average, and then comparing each grade and dividing data into two categories : good and poor (depends if below or above average)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("scores.txt");
    Scanner read = new Scanner (fis);
    int count=0, id;
    double total=0,average, grade;
    String line;
    Scanner stringScanner;
    while(read.hasNextLine()){
        line = read.nextLine();
        stringScanner = new Scanner(line);
        id = stringScanner.nextInt();
        while (stringScanner.hasNextDouble()){
            total = total + stringScanner.nextDouble();
            count++;
        }
        stringScanner.close();
    }
    average = total/count;
    System.out.println("The average is : "+ average);
    read.close();

    fis = new FileInputStream ("scores.txt");
    read = new Scanner (fis);
    while(read.hasNextLine()){
        line=read.nextLine();
        stringScanner=new Scanner (line);
        id = stringScanner.nextInt();
        while (stringScanner.hasNextDouble()){
            grade = stringScanner.nextDouble();
            if(grade >= average){
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("good.txt");
                PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter (fos);
                pr.print(id + "/t"+ grade);
                pr.println();
            }
            else if (grade<average){
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("poor.txt");
                PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter (fos);
                pr.print(id + "/t"+ grade);
                pr.println();
            }
            else System.out.println("test");
        }
        stringScanner.close();
    }
    fis.close();
    read.close();
    System.out.println("Files have been created...");
}
```

I think I got it all right in terms of calculating the average (as it outputs it correctly). However, I'm having a trouble writing on the poor and good text files, those are created but they remain empty. How can I make the program write on the two files and what exactly is missing from my code?
Thank you.

Edit : 
Here's how the .txt file looks like :

```
206527     44.24
208530     75.38
207135     85.61
205241     91.51
204324     50.61
203357     68.28
202117     57.11
```

Comment: Can you provide the txt file!

Comment: Added,

Update :
I just solved it using arrays. However, I'm still curious as the instructor may require something like : Solve by reading the file twice and without using arrays. It happens. :)

Comment: Isn't the solution I provided below just the thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In short: it happens because you **don't call `close()` on `PrintWriter`**. Apart from this, it'll be obviously more effective, if you don't open the file every time you want to add something to it. Open both files once at the beginning and then write to them. After your job is done, remember to close everything that you've opened. Below is the second part of your program:

```
fis = new FileInputStream("scores.txt");
read = new Scanner(fis);
FileOutputStream fosGood = new FileOutputStream("good.txt");
PrintWriter prGood = new PrintWriter(fosGood);
FileOutputStream fosPoor = new FileOutputStream("poor.txt");
PrintWriter prPoor = new PrintWriter(fosPoor);
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
    line = read.nextLine();
    stringScanner = new Scanner(line);
    id = stringScanner.nextInt();
    while (stringScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        grade = stringScanner.nextDouble();
        if (grade >= average)
            prGood.println(id + "\t" + grade);
        else if (grade < average)
            prPoor.println(id + "\t" + grade);
        else System.out.println("test");
    }
    stringScanner.close();
}
prGood.close();
prPoor.close();
fis.close();
fosGood.close();
fosPoor.close();
read.close();
System.out.println("Files have been created...");
```

Besides, you shouldn't throw any exceptions from your `main` method, but rather place your code in `try/catch/finally` block. In such case, all the code regarding closing the files, would go into the `finally`. Optionally you could employ [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).